# How do we integrate Saxon with Visual Studio?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0

Hello people is it true that we cannot integrate Saxon with Visual Studio?

Because I've read this thread: [XSLT 2.0 intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 - Adding a schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116854/xslt-2-0-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2010-adding-a-schema) and it seems that Martin has some way of integrating Saxon with Visual studio (but he's not saying how)

This thread also confirms my doubt that we can actually integrate Saxon with Visual Studio (but doesn't say how): [Using Saxon .NET XSLT processor does not work with intellisense in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750841/saxon-net-xslt-2-0-processor)

So I've tried searching for how to integrate Saxon with Visual Studio and found alot of places saying that we can't do it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/e4c9d366-bad3-4376-a15b-00e4c4bf7620/ and [Saxon with Visual Studio 2010 - is there a way to use the debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099051/saxon-with-visual-studio-2010-is-there-a-way-to-use-the-debugger)

So basically my problem is that I want the Visual Studio Intellisense support and I want XSLT 2.0 (yea the best of both words =P) What's the best solution for it?

Btw did anyone manage to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: I prefer using Saxon from the XSelerator -- much more convenient than with any other IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course use Visual Studio to develop C# applications that invoke the Saxon processor using the Saxon API - just include the Saxon DLLs in your project as you would any other third-party library.

But I don't think that's the question you are asking; you are asking about using Visual Studio to develop code in XSLT 2.0; and no, there's no built-in support for that. But there are plenty of third (or fourth?) party XSLT 2.0 development tools around, for example oXygen. Some of them (e.g. Liquid XML Studio?) may be able to function as Visual Studio plugins - but I can't confirm that.